# Display Header on Textbox only if text is set in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to modify the look & feel of the textbox control in a UWP App to what our designers drawn in sketch. That includes to have a header only shown when no text is set in the textbox.

I assume that I have to modify the visibility of the HeaderContentPresenter and its DataTemplate:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,2" Grid.Row="0" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

I wrote an IValueConvert to convert "empty string" to visibility, but I am stuck with the binding. I can't see any way to get the datacontext.

```
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{StaticResource DarkGrey}" FontSize="10" FontFamily="TheSansB4SemiLight" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

How can I access the text written on the textbox within the DataTemplate?

Thanks

## Update with Code

**I want this**
[image: SampleControl]

**MainPage.xaml**

Three Textboxes I applied the same style to.

```
    <TextBox Header="Username" PlaceholderText="Username" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="20,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Style="{StaticResource InputField}" />
    <TextBox Header="Surname" PlaceholderText="Surname" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="20,249,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Style="{StaticResource InputField}"/>
    <TextBox Header="Name" PlaceholderText="Name" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="20,196,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Style="{StaticResource InputField}"/>
```

**Styles.xaml**

Basic shareable styles within a ResourceDict, refrenced in App.xaml. When I name the textboxes "InputField", the mechanism starts working, but obviously I have name conflicts and strange behavior.

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource DarkGrey}" 
                    FontSize="10" 
                    FontFamily="TheSansB4SemiLight"
                    Visibility="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=InputField}"
                    Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=InputField}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

**Question**

What element within the Template must be named to be accessible through binding? I assume it's one of the elements the textbox control is made of, but I can't find out how.

```
<Grid><Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" MinWidth="34" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,2" Grid.Row="0" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: On a side note: From a UX point of view this concept is terrible. Any chance you can convince your designers to rethink this?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thx for your feedback. It's already implemented in a CSS Framework and productive. I just need to transfer some of the stuff to xaml which is harder than I thought. You are right, not sure if I like the concept at all, but its what I have to implement right now.

Comment: That's unfortunate but maybe someone on [UX Stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) could give you some pointers on how to improve this. Jumping textboxes are never a good idea. Maybe hide the title instead of collapsing it?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure if the "jumping" is desired. I recognized the same, that's why I try to hide the control. I modified it to stay the same height what I think is a reasonable change. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

> There are 2 solutions here.
>
> 1. Hide/Show TextBox Header based on Converter and TextBox.Text Length
> 2. Hide/Show TextBox Header based on CustomControl and Lost/Gain Focus

**1) Hide/Show TextBox Header based on Converter and TextBox.Text Length**

You need to Name your `TextBox` inside `DataTemplate` so that binding can find the item and Process the value.

Below is a sample of **Converter**.

```
public class DataToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Visibility dataVisible = (value.ToString().Length == 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        return dataVisible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And below is how I use it in a **DataTemplate** inside `ListView`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"  TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                    <TextBox.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Header String" Visibility="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource DataToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=textBox}"/>
                    </TextBox.Header>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Final Result**

[image]

**Edit**

After you updated your question things got more simpler.

**2. Hide/Show TextBox Header based on CustomControl and Lost/Gain Focus**

You need to create a custom control to handle events that are common across for your textblock.

So as per your image, When you get focus, you show Header and lose focus, you hide it since there is text in placeholder.

Below is a custom control that does exactly that.

```
public sealed class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBox);
        this.GotFocus += MyTextBox_GotFocus;
        this.LostFocus += MyTextBox_LostFocus;
    }

    private void MyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Header = "";
    }

    private void MyTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Header = this.PlaceholderText;
    }
}
```

And the usage will be

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:MyTextBox PlaceholderText="User Name" x:Name="txtUserName" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
    <local:MyTextBox PlaceholderText="Email" x:Name="txtEmail" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
    <local:MyTextBox PlaceholderText="Password" x:Name="txtPassword" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh no, really? That easy? Took me hours :-( I thought there must be some way of accessing the data without dealing with a x:Name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, but wait. I want to use this behavior as a shareable style. When using element name, that would only work for one element and not for every textbox on my page. Any idea ? RelativeSource={RelativeSource  
                      TemplatedParent} looks promising, but again not sure how to get the values.

Comment: If you want to use this as shareable resource, I would suggest you to create a custom control so that it can be reusable.

Comment: Yes, thats one way I will consider. But I still stuck with how to access the text within the template as your suggestion works only for a specific, named, control. I really have no Idea how to access the text in my case. Any hint ?

Comment: @BenAffleckIsBatman Where is the button to get Text from `TextBox`? Inside `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I updated my post with code sample to be more clear on what I want. Could you please have a look? Thanks

Comment: @BenAffleckIsBatman This still begs the same question. Where is the button that is used to access data from Text? Is it inside the data template? or is there a button outside your data template?

Comment: If you look at the sample code, there is not button involved at all. It's a simple textbox with a header set. The header should only be visible when the user set focus on the textbox and starts typing into it. So header visibility should bind to text property of the textbox and convert its state to visibility.

Comment: Now as per your Question on Text from TextBox within DataTemplate, How do you distinguish which textbox is for what when they are in listview? I would rather suggest you to work with Grid and Rows to set up all your TextBoxes and get data by Name parameter. Or if you want to get Text from a particular Row, Have a Button inside data template, use `FindName()` and Get TextBox Text. These are the best ways you can achieve what you are looking for If you use ListView.

Comment: I think we have a miscommunication here. I've never mentioned a listview. Simple Textboxes, out of the box. Why do you think I'm talking about a listview? The sample consists of three plan textboxes drag'n'dropped on an empty page control. Could you please check again ? Still need your help.